# Calculating SUM in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate the SUM of the number of orders for each product and then display ONLY the products that have the largest number of orders. So if 2 products have the same number of orders, the query should display both, otherwise just the top one.

My schema is the following:

```
 Product(
          **product_id**, 
          product_category, 
          client_id, 
          num_order
 )
```

I would really appreciate some help as I'm a beginner with MySql and trying to learn.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "display ONLY the products that have the largest number of orders" isn't specific enough.  You need to provide some sample data and work through what you want for the results.

Answer (score 4):

Try this approach using a subquery:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM product
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING SUM(num_order) = (
    SELECT SUM(num_order)
    FROM product
    GROUP BY product_id
    ORDER BY SUM(num_order) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

And here's a variation using `MAX`:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM product
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING SUM(num_order) = (
    SELECT MAX(num_order)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT SUM(num_order) AS num_order
        FROM product
        GROUP BY product_id
    ) T1
)
```

Comment: You ignored the OP's request to SUM order (but then then the OP wasn't very clear in the problem specification)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer the question without a better explanation of the requirements.

Comment: Apologies for not being more specific. The above query returns a single order that has the largest number of orders. What if I have more than one product having an equal number of orders? I think I should be using SUM,MAX and possibly ALL but I can't really get around this problem. Any further thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks for your time!

Comment: @sp_key: I've provided a variation that uses both `SUM` and `MAX`.

Comment: Hi Mark, many thanks for your persistence in trying to teach me. This time it returns the following error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row. I experimented a bit with derived tables and creating alias tables but I guess the problem is that I'm trying to display more than one field? Any way of doing this?